# Map<Id,List<String>> NEED TO GET Seperatd values from Multipicklist in a query

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, map

I have a scenario where i need to get multipicklist values from a query which are semicolon seperated values.I need to get them as Map<Id,list>and then i need to compare with another list of strings.to get the output.
below is my code.
Sub_Product_Line__c is mUltipicklist field

```
    list<Document_Type_Maintenance__c> documentType=[Select Name,Sub_Product_Line__c from Document_Type_Maintenance__c
                                                     where Document_Type_Record_Type__c='Job' and 
                                                     Product_Line__c =:productLine]; 
    System.debug('DTM'+documentType);
    Map<Id,list<String>> newmap= new map<Id,list<String>>();
    for(Document_Type_Maintenance__c dtms : documentType) {
        if(newmap.containsKey(dtms.Id)) {
            list<String> subProduct = newmap.get(dtms.id);
            subProduct.add(dtms.Sub_Product_Line__c);
            newmap.put(dtms.id, subProduct);
        } 
    }
```

here is another set subproductlines i have which queried from another object. I already got a set of values form the map.so  i need to compare these sub productlines in two sets and i need to get common values and get the iD ,name of the record that have outcome subproduct lines

Comment: use the String class `split` method to get a collection of each MSP from the database field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multipicklist values are returned as a semi-colon separated string. For example, if you have picklist item API names of A, B, C and D and the user selects A and C, you get back a value of "A;C".

To get the individual picklist selections, simply use `myString.split(';')`.

Also note that switching to Set from List might be sensible if you want to do comparison as you mention at the end of the question; for a set there is no order consideration when comparing, whereas order is relevant in a List.

I think it fair to say that you need to update your code like:

```
    Map<String, Set<String>> subProductLinesByDTMId = new Map<String, Set<String>>();

    for (Document_Type_Maintenance__c dtms : documentType) {
        Set<String> subProductLines = new Set<String>();

        // Get hold of a list with the dtms sub product lines, if there are any.
        // This always provides at least an empty set
        if (dtms.Sub_Product_Line__c != null) {
            subProductLines.addAll(dtms.Sub_Product_Line__c.split(';'));
        }

        // The assumption here is that the dtms Id is unique during this
        // for loop iteration
        subProductLinesByDTMId.put(dtms.Id, subProductLines);
    }
```

Using Set instead of List means we know we a) only have unique sub product lines in the value and b) can easily compare with other sets and not worry that insertion order causes us to fail to match when it should.

Comment: How can we Compare a Set<String> and Map<Id,Set<String> >in Apex.As i am getting here a MAP and i already have set before this

Comment: Clearly you wouldn't compare `Set<String>` with `Map<Id, Set<String>>`. The question is, what is it that you are trying to achieve? Perhaps you could [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/333118/edit) your question to add detail (at the end, after what you already asked) as to just what you want to subsequently compare and why?